# Consider the question, "Aside from his pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> Aside from his pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?

Doesn't this imply that the person asking also considers the subject's pronunciation as a mistake? How should it be rewritten to clarify that the pronunciation is not considered a mistake?

Comment: Welcome! I think the sentence is acknowledging that there were pronunciation issues, yes. Regarding rewriting, do you mean you want the sentence to say that there were no pronunciation mistakes, or to say that pronunciation issues are not to be considered mistakes?

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for welcoming here, and for answering my first question. Regarding rewriting, I have in mind the second, that pronunciation issues are not be considered mistakes.

Comment: //Aside from his pronunciation....//? I think this usage is not that common.  Shouldn't it be "Apart from his pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?"

Comment: "What if any mistakes did he make (leaving aside any punctuation errors that he may have made)?" Note that overlooking an error does not stop it being an error.

Comment: Not counting pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?

Comment: If pronunciation were not a criterion, it wouldn't have been considered. The general doesn't go up to his Lieutenant General and say "Aside from their yodeling, what mistakes did my soldiers make today?"

Comment: To remove the ambiguity: Excluding pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?

Comment: 'What mistakes did he make?'

Answer (score 1):

> > Aside from his pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?
>
> How should it be rewritten to clarify that the pronunciation is not considered a mistake?

"His pronunciation **was excellent, but** what mistakes did he make?"

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence does not necessarily mean that there were any mistakes in pronunciation. It may be the case that the speaker does not know whether there were any such mistakes. If there certainly were, then you could say:

> Aside from his pronunciation, what other mistakes did he make?

However, this would actually be better:

> Aside from mistakes in his pronunciation, what other mistakes did he make?

If there were certainly no pronunciation errors and you wanted to indicate that, then I think you'd have to do so explicitly. For example:

> His pronunciation was correct, so what mistakes did he make?

Answer (score 0):

*Aside from his pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?* implies that pronunciation is being considered as a mistake. In order to exclude pronunciation from being considered a mistake I would say: "Not taking into consideration his pronunciation, what mistakes did he make?"

Comment: This answer only addresses part of the question.

Comment: It should be clarified that the sentence implies that in the ordinary, everyday, sense of *imply*, but it (arguably) does not imply it as a matter of logic.

Answer (score -1):

As the others already stated, indeed it implies that the pronunciation was also a mistake. I think a proper rewrite could be: **"What mistakes did he make? Was it pronunciation or something else, grammar maybe?**" or simply **"What kind of mistakes did he make?**" - this latter question implying an answer that clarifies the errors said person has made.